# How long will it take to get used to current level of exercise?

Tags: walking, overtraining

Right now I am not exercising. As in 0 formal exercise. I believe in integrating physical activity that I like in my daily life, as opposed to formal exercising in the gym.

Except I have two puppies who are super-high energy. They require about 1.5 hours of walking a day, and I don't drive. Grand total 3-ish hours of walking a day. Also the younger puppy weighs 20-25 kg (50-ish lbs) and needs to be carried downstairs in my arms 4-5 times a day as I can't trust him he won't pee in the hallway. (apartment building). Add regular hiking on the weekends (I love nature).

As a result I am clearly overtrained. Sore, no appetite, lack of energy, yet another cold today. Taking a few days off, hiring a dog walker.

How long will it be til I adjust to this level of physical activity?

Answer (score 1):

If you literally started with 0 physical activity and started doing all of this, I understand the soreness. Given you eat and rest enough, your body will get used to this within a month or two, during which it will gradually become less intense for you.

I wouldn't say you're overtrained though. It just sounds like your body is adjusting to the activities it's not used to, being sore and tired is a part of this proces. Being overtrained is something else entirely.